# How to handle click events on divs with React and Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a custom Card component, which gets an "onClick" type, to handle clicking like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './card.module.css';

interface Card {
    onClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement>;
}

const Card: React.FC<Card> = ({ children }) => {
    return <div className={styles.card}>{children}</div>;
};

export default Card;
```

I'm using `Card` to compose another component called `PostCard` like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from '../Card';
import styles from './postcard.module.css';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

type PostCard = {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    slug: string;
};

const PostCard: React.FC<PostCard> = ({ title, description, slug }) => {
    const router = useRouter();

    const handleClick: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement> = (e) => {
        console.log('here');
        e.preventDefault();
        router.push('/blog/[slug]', `/blog/${slug}`, { slug });
    };
    return (
        <Card onClick={handleClick}>
            <h2 className={styles.title}>{title}</h2>
            <p className={styles.paragraph}>{description}</p>
        </Card>
    );
};

export default PostCard;
```

When `PostCard` is clicked, I want it to use the `router` function from `next.js` and push the page to a new page. How ever, when I click on `PostCard` nothing happens. What's going on? Nothing is printed to the console from `handleClick` so I'm pretty sure the click isn't being registered by the Card component. Should I be passing the onClick function to the `Card` component?

Comment: Am just curious what does ```e.preventDefault();``` stop on a HTMLDivElement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `onClick` needs to be on the div tag instead on Card, here you are sending the `handleClick` function as a prop to the Card component (onClick), so you need to accept that prop in the Card component and put the function on onClick of the div rendered.

In `PostCard`

```js
return (
        <Card handleClick={handleClick}>
            <h2 className={styles.title}>{title}</h2>
            <p className={styles.paragraph}>{description}</p>
        </Card>
    );
```

We can send prop as `handleClick` instead of `onClick` to avoid confusion.

And in the `Card` component

```js
const Card: React.FC<Card> = ({ children, handleClick }) => {
    return <div onClick={handleClick} className={styles.card}>{children}</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using `onClick` on the `Card` but the `Card` returns a div with the children and the `onClick` prop is not used anywhere.

Try this:

```
<Card clicked={handleClick}>
    <h2 className={styles.title}>{title}</h2>
    <p className={styles.paragraph}>{description}</p>
</Card>


const Card: React.FC<Card> = ({ children, clicked }) => {
    return <div onClick={clicked} className={styles.card}>{children}</div>;
};
```

The interface should also be changed:

```
interface Card {
    clicked: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLDivElement>;
}
```